# Extracting text from animated GIF file

Tags: images, conversion, image-processing, gif, animated-gif

I have a GIF file that shows a scrolling down through a table. That table has data that I need to extract. Here is how the file looks like, [image]

BTW, I have video files that show the same. With extensions mp4, flv and avi. If it's easier to extract the data from those video files, kindly, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You can't "extract" text from a picture or video file.  You can however use an OCR program to try and figure it out. https://geekflare.com/convert-image-to-text/